# Как получить количество записанных элементов в файле?

Tags: c++

Как получить количество записанных символов в файле?

Comment: что такое елемент?

Comment: Записать количество записанных элементов в файл, затем прочитать.

Comment: Например я записал (1,2,3,4 ....) в файл как вывести их количество.

Comment: Нужна функция которая сама в файле посчитает их количество.

Comment: Нет готовой функции. Читайте по-одному, когда больше не сможете - элементы закончились.

Comment: @Андрей Пушкин: Ну вот когда вы их записывали, тогда и надо было их считать. Посчитали - вывели. В чем проблема?

Comment: Текстовый файл или бинарный?

Comment: Текстовый файл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы пишите элементы в файле через пробел, то количество элементов будет: количество пробелов + 1.
1 – первый элемент в файле.